# Construct a Non-deterministic Finite State Automaton (NFA)

Tags: regular-language

Construct a Non-deterministic Finite State Automaton (NFA) M with minimum number of states for the set of strings over {0, 1} such that each 0 in the string is immediately followed by a 1.

The image below is the NFA i've drawn. However i do not know if it is correct.
[NFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/875LC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your automaton is not correct. It accepts the word $0100$ which is not in the language.

**Hint**. There is a two-state deterministic automaton that recognizes your language.

Comment: oh ok thank you so much